The mandatory attribute 'async' is missing in tag 'amphtml engine script'
I am getting this error with amp validator

anybody please help me fix this problems. now i cant not input pixel code to the coding.
and when i test my page in URL Inspection I got:
Linked AMP version is invalid

Welcome to Stack Overflow!, Please take the tour, and read how to ask, an On Topic question, then look at the Question Check list, the perfect question and how to create a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example
